# Help with tensor calculus identity proof (antisymmetric matrix and levi civita symbol)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, tensor-calculus, vectors

I'm having some trouble with 2 identitys from tensor calculus. I need to proof these two guys:

> 2. in euclidean 3-dimensional space, an antisymmetric matrix with entries $M_{ij}$ is equivalent to a vector $v^k=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{kij}\,\,M_{ij}$
> 3. the inverse formula is $M_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}\,\,v^k$

I know that the levi civita symbol is totally  antisymmetric, and so any other totally  antisymmetric  object Mij will be proportional  to  the  levi-civita symbol, but I just cant see the two informations adding up.

I appreciate any hint!

Comment: Have you tried writing these out explicitly? For example, what is $v^1$? What is $M_{23}$? I am a huge proponent of understanding formulas explicitly first and abstractly second.

Comment: For the non-explicit approach, do you know about contractions of products of Levi-Civita symbols in terms of Kronecker deltas?

Comment: @G.Smith I'm having trouble in understanding the conection between this vector and the  antisymmetric matrix. And about the the contraction of the product of Levi-Civita symbols: do you refer to the identity epsilon_ijk * epsilon_imn = delta_jm * delta kn - delta_jn*delta_km??

Comment: @CaueEvangelista Think about how many independent components has an antisymmetric matrix in 3D euclidean and then how many independent components has a vector in 3D space. What those formulas are saying is that the two objects are essentially the same.

Comment: *I'm having trouble in understanding the conection between this vector and the antisymmetric matrix.* If you use the formulas to write out explicitly what a component like $v^1$ is in terms of components of $M$, and what $M_{23}$ is in terms of components of $v$, I think you *will* understand the connection. To do this you must understand the *numerical* values of all the components of $\epsilon$.

Comment: It seems like your second formula should not have the 1/2. You are apparently being asked to prove something that isn’t true! See page 58 [here](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/reh10/lectures/nst-mmii-chapter3.pdf). I hope your problem did not come from a textbook.

Comment: @G.Smith, it is a problem from a textbook!! Thank you for pointing this!!!

Comment: By the way, this kind of equivalence is called a duality.

Comment: I want to thank you all, the page 58 and the G.Smith explicit approach helped me!!! One way to show this is: explicitly show that the first expression is true and then use it along side with the identy posted by @joigus and page 58 to show that the second one is also true. You rock, guys.

Answer (score 2):

The more ways you have to convince yourself that something is correct, the better. Try G. Smith's approach, then think that $M_{ij}$ and $v^k$ have the same number of independent components, as,
$$
\frac{n\left(n-1\right)}{2}=\frac{3\left(3-1\right)}{2}=3
$$
And finally, an identity to consider that will help you solve this and, e.g., prove many identities of vector calculus is,
$$
\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon^{kmn}=\left.\delta_{i}\right.^{m}\left.\delta_{j}\right.^{n}-\left.\delta_{i}\right.^{n}\left.\delta_{j}\right.^{m}
$$